# Angular CLI working but not reacting to commands

Tags: angular, console

I've tried to add a new component to my angular project by typing in console

```
ng generate component heroes
```

But for some reason, angular is not responding to commands while project is running. I just can't type anything in console. However, I know it's not crashed becouse I can still change stuff and it will rebuild the project.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Is your terminal instance in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of your command line interpretor. Basically, when you run `npm start`, the thread is used and dedicated to this command.

If you want to still use the CLI while the server is running, you can simply open a new terminal and run these command in the second terminal.

Comment: Oh... I didn't think of opening a new terminal